# When I write into CSV file, it writes only the second time

Tags: python, csv

I am in the learning process and I face this problem..

```
writer = csv.writer(open("db.csv", "w"))
connection = sqlite3.connect('hx.db')
cur_baseboard = connection.cursor()
cur_baseboard.execute('select * from baseboard')
writer.writerows(cur_baseboard)
```

When I run this code, the first time it creates the csv file db.csv, but writes nothing in it.
After I run it the second time, it fills with the values in db!
Where did I went wrong? Please, enlighten me.

Comment: Perhaps the write is buffered, try `del writer` after `writerows`.

Answer (score 3):

You're not closing the underlying file at the end, so the data is not flushed. Also, you should use the "b" flag to make sure the file is opened in binary mode. ( http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer ) Use:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
with open("db.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    [...]
# File is closed automatically after end of with block.
```

Comment: Bad way of handling files, see my answer.

Comment: Which answer? Also, which of the two ways?

Comment: `from future import ...` has not been necessary for the use of `with` since Python 2.6.

Comment: The second one using context management is fine, except you only really needed the future import in Python < 2.6.

Comment: I think I'll actually delete the first version. Sadly some people still have to work on pre-2.6 Pythons so I'll leave in the import.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the with statement to ensure that everything gets written to the fileobj as soon as its finished.

```
with open('db.csv','wb') as fi:
    writer = csv.writer(fi)
```

Of course you won't have with in some of the earlier pythons but you can always future import it

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

EDIT: Changed to open in binary mode, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: OPEN THE FILE IN BINARY MODE!

Comment: Done. Thanks for pointing it out, been a while since I have used csv.

Answer (score 0):

It is perhaps that your sql is returned an empty string for the first time? It is not a problem with csv module, just use your first and last line and instead of `cur_baseboard`, write a random text and you will find that it will always get written.